# Cant access protected resources even after successful login ( passport oauth2.0 google sign in )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js

Facing Trouble making protected Resources accessible to Logged in users ( oauth2 google passport.js )

I am able to login and then get redirected to the protected page ( on the frontend).

But when the page renders i send a request to a route in the api called /login/success where i send some user details as response , but before that i check if req.isAuthenticated exists , apparently it exists in the route to which the callback url after google log in , ( callback - ive named it {BACKEND_BASE_URL}/authorize ) redirects ( req.user and req.isAuthenticated ) , but it doesnt seem to exist in any other routes , i am confused right now , i am a noob so i dont exactly know if i should run the passport.authenticate middleware before the logic in all protected Routes or if it should be done only once ---

https://github.com/DAObliterator/oauth2_googlesigin... here is the link to the project.

FLOW

```
/*{CLIENT_URL}/authenticate -> (NOTE - via an anchor tag does not  work when i send a get request using axios when click event is fired , throws a NO ACCESS CONTROL ORIGIN on the requested header error at the client side , had to sit a whole day to figure out that anchor tags has to be used to prevent CORS error )*/

//{BACKEND_URL}/login ->

app.get(
"/login",
passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["email", "profile"] })
);

//Auth Server (google) ->

//{BACKEND_URL}/authorize->

app.get(
"/authorize",
passport.authenticate("google", {
successRedirect: "/protected",
failureRedirect: "/auth/failure",
})
);

//onSuccess

//{BACKEND_URL}/protected->

app.get("/protected", async (req, res) => {
console.log("user-details-2 ", req.user);
if (req.user) {
return res.redirect(\${process.env.CLIENT_URL}protectedPage`);`
} else {
return res.redirect(\${process.env.CLIENT_URL}authenticate`);`
}
});

//{CLIENT_URL}/protectedPage

import React , { useState , useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

export const ProtectedPage = () => {

const [text , setText ] = useState("");
const [access, setAccess] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
axios.get("http://localhost:6046/login/success").then((response) => {
console.log(response.data , "response data from /protected \n");
setAccess(true);
setText(response.data.user.displayName);
}).catch((error) => {
console.log(error , ' error happened while trying to access protectedResource endpoint')
})
},[])

const handleLogout = () => {
axios.get("http://localhost:6046/logout")
}

return (
<div id="Main" className="w-screen h-screen flex flex-col">
Hello to ProtectedPage <br /> you are{" "}
{access ? text + " and is permitted " : "not-permitted"} to view the protected Resource
{access && (
<button
id="Logout-btn"
className="bg-blue-400 h-16 w-40"
onClick={handleLogout}
>
logout
</button>
)}
</div>
);
}

//{BACKEND_URL}/login/success

app.get("/login/success", (req, res) => {
if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
// If the user is authenticated, respond with user information
res.status(200).json({
error: false,
message: "Successfully Logged In",
user: req.user,
});
} else {
// If the user is not authenticated, respond with an error
res.status(403).json({ error: true, message: "Not Authorized" });
}
});
```

throws 403 error on the client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was not setting withCredentials to true when sending requests , because of which cookies where not being included in the request